# Event handlers not responding

Tags: javascript, d3.js, events

I'm beginning with JavaScript and D3 and trying to write a simple code that allows users to draw a curve on a canvas. The first step is being able to detect when a mouse button is down, so that if the mouse moved while the button was down, data would be recorded.

I tried changing ".on" to ".addEventListener" with the same results. Also, I'm using Firefox.

When reading the code below, I know it makes little sense to have the flag clickState incremented every time the mouse is moved; I only did that for debugging purposes to see if the function mousemovefx was being called upon mouse motion.

When I open this webpage, the text in the output div changes immediately to "Down" and nothing I do (e.g. clicking and moving in the canvas) changes it. None of the other functions seem to be executed either.

I neither understand (a) why the handlers aren't being called on those events nor (b) why the mousedown handler is being called immediately, when not only am I not clicking but my mouse isn't even on the canvas.

```
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";

    canvw = 500;
    canvh = 500;
    border = 6;

    clickState = 0;

    var canvas = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")      //Add an SVG to the body
                    .attr("width",canvw+2*border)
                    .attr("height",canvh+2*border)

    var canvbg = canvas.append("rect")
                    .attr("x",border)
                    .attr("y",border)
                    .attr("width",canvw)
                    .attr("height",canvh)
                    .attr("fill","white")
                    .attr("stroke","rgb(200,200,200)")
                    .attr("stroke-width",5)

    var mydiv = d3.select("body")
                    .append("div")
                    .attr("id","outputdiv")
                    .style("color","orange")

    canvas.on("mousedown", mousedownfx());

    canvas.on("mouseup", mouseupfx());

    canvas.on("mousemove",mousemovefx());

    canvas.on("mouseout",mouseoutfx());

    function mousedownfx() {
        clickState = 1;
        mydiv.text("Down")
    }

    function mouseupfx() {
        clickState = 0;
        mydiv.text("Up")
    }

    function mousemovefx() {
        mydiv.text(clickState)
        clickState = clickState + 1;
    }

    function mouseoutfx() {
        clickstate = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";

    canvw = 500;
    canvh = 500;
    border = 6;

    clickState = 0;

    var canvas = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")      //Add an SVG to the body
                    .attr("width",canvw+2*border)
                    .attr("height",canvh+2*border)

    var canvbg = canvas.append("rect")
                    .attr("x",border)
                    .attr("y",border)
                    .attr("width",canvw)
                    .attr("height",canvh)
                    .attr("fill","white")
                    .attr("stroke","rgb(200,200,200)")
                    .attr("stroke-width",5)

    var mydiv = d3.select("body")
                    .append("div")
                    .attr("id","outputdiv")
                    .style("color","orange")

    canvas.on("mousedown", mousedownfx);

    canvas.on("mouseup", mouseupfx);

    canvas.on("mousemove",mousemovefx);

    canvas.on("mouseout",mouseoutfx);

    function mousedownfx() {
        clickState = 1;
        mydiv.text("Down")
    }

    function mouseupfx() {
        clickState = 0;
        mydiv.text("Up")
    }

    function mousemovefx() {
        mydiv.text(clickState)
        clickState = clickState + 1;
    }

    function mouseoutfx() {
        clickstate = 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

When you are setting the listeners you are calling the function change:

```
canvas.on("mousedown", mousedownfx());
canvas.on("mouseup", mouseupfx());
canvas.on("mousemove",mousemovefx());
canvas.on("mouseout",mouseoutfx());
```

To:

```
canvas.on("mousedown", mousedownfx);
canvas.on("mouseup", mouseupfx);
canvas.on("mousemove",mousemovefx);
canvas.on("mouseout",mouseoutfx);
```

This will pass the function, which will then be called when the button is clicked.

Comment: I just tried your recommendation but now the handlers aren't being called at all - nothing appears in the output div.

Comment: Could you post a working example? Would help see what exactly is wrong

Comment: @BGreen I added a snippet with a working example. Cannot seem to replicate your problem, after my recommended changes. Also as a note I am using Chrome

Comment: I just tried your snippet and it works. I copied it and ran it from an HTML document in my drive and it worked. I'll look through line by line and see what I overlooked, or where the typo is... I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: Apparently I just failed to change "addEventListener" back to "on" and that caused an issue somehow. I don't know why, since I thought the arguments of addEventListener were the same as those of on - an event specifying the string and then the function to be called, without parentheses.

Comment: D3 selections don't have an `addEventListener` property, so that was probably the problem.

Comment: Right - it wasn't just a vanilla JS object, but one from D3 - thank you!